# Postgres equivalent of Oracle's RMAN.VALIDATE_DATABASE

Tags: postgresql, oracle, migration

I am migrating a system using Oracle DB to Postgres (12.7). Various checks are run weekly against the existing DB, including a RMAN.VALIDATE_DATABASE (actually RDSADMIN.RDSADMIN_RMAN_UTIL.VALIDATE_DATABASE as it's Amazon RDS) - physical+logical type. Is there an equivalent to this with Postgres?

The Oracle DB runs as an Amazon RDS instance, the Postgres DB is running as an Amazon Aurora instance.

I can see that I can enable block checksums, but I don't see anything else.

Thanks!

Comment: So what exactly does that procedure validate? Also: why start with Postgres 12 on a new project? You should use Postgres 14

Comment: At this time 12.7 is the latest supported by AWS Aurora, it is somewhat behind as I think they have to rework parts of it. From Oracle page "Use the VALIDATE command to check for corrupt blocks and missing files, or to determine whether a backup set can be restored."

Answer (score 1):

The procedure *tries* to ensure that the backup pieces available can be used to restore the database.
I don't know if there's any equivalent for PostgreSQL.

However, the only way to be *absolutely certain* that a database *can* be recovered is ...   to restore [a copy of] that database.

Just because a procedure *says* that everything is OK is *no substitute* for proper **Disaster Recovery** Rehearsals wherein you actually restore the database to

- Definitively *prove* that the database *can* be restored, and
- Remind you how to do the restore because, hopefully, it's *not* something that you'll be doing on a regular basis, otherwise.

Comment: I don't know what my client's disaster recovery procedure is, but you are correct. Using the VALIDATE_DATABASE function presumably gives them a degree of confidence.

Comment: @DavidKerr: if you want to validate your backups, you need to first tell us which backup tool you are using? barman? pgBackrest? pgProBackup? Something written in-house?

Comment: I am new to Oracle and Postgre admin tasks like this. The validation is done in a separate script to backup. The various end-of-week tasks are orchestrated using another tool (Control M). The backup proc is in-house using DBMS_DATAPUMP in EXPORT mode, which then writes that file to S3. I don't know what their disaster recovery procedure is.